# what is the subtitute for avio_set_interrupt_cb?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

Is the avio_set_interrupt_cb deprecated in the new ffmpeg release?
What is the substitute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Here is how it's done

You define the call back

```
int decode_interrupt_cb(void * ctx) {
    return isQuit;
}
```

Make a call back struct

```
const AVIOInterruptCB int_cb = { decode_interrupt_cb, NULL };
```

Assign it to you `AVFormatContext`'s `interrupt_callback` before any file reading

```
pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback = int_cb;
```

if you open file with 'avio_open2', use it like this:

```
int errCode = avio_open2(&pFormatCtx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_READ, &pFormatCtx->interrupt_callback, NULL);
```

Hope someone find it helpful.